# Java Android, error when decoding AES-256

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography, aes

I'm trying to decrypt some text and I get an error:

> javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: error:06065064:digital envelope
>    routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt
>    com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.EVP_CipherFinal_ex(Native
>    Method)  com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLCipher.doFinalInternal(OpenSSLCipher.java:430)
>   com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLCipher.engineDoFinal(OpenSSLCipher.java:466)javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:1340)

```
import android.util.Base64;

import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class AESEncrypter {

    private static final byte[] SALT = {
            (byte) 0xA9, (byte) 0x9B, (byte) 0xC8, (byte) 0x32,
            (byte) 0x56, (byte) 0x35, (byte) 0xE3, (byte) 0x03
    };
    private static final int ITERATION_COUNT = 65536;
    private static final int KEY_LENGTH = 256;
    private Cipher ecipher;
    private Cipher dcipher;

    public AESEncrypter(String passPhrase) throws Exception {
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(passPhrase.toCharArray(), SALT, ITERATION_COUNT, KEY_LENGTH);
        SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

        ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"); // "AES/CBC/NoPadding"
        ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);

        dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        byte[] iv = ecipher.getParameters().getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
        dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
    }

    public String encrypt(String encrypt) throws Exception {
        encrypt = encrypt.replace("\n", "");

        byte[] bytes = encrypt.getBytes("UTF8");
        byte[] encrypted = encrypt(bytes);
        return Base64.encodeToString(encrypted, Base64.DEFAULT);
    }

    public byte[] encrypt(byte[] plain) throws Exception {
        return ecipher.doFinal(plain);
    }

    public String decrypt(String encrypt) throws Exception {
        encrypt = encrypt.replace("\n", "");
        byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(encrypt, Base64.DEFAULT);
        byte[] decrypted = decrypt(bytes);
        return new String(decrypted, "UTF8");
    }

    public byte[] decrypt(byte[] encrypt) throws Exception {
        return dcipher.doFinal(encrypt);
    }

}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you call `decrypt`? Where did you get the ciphertext from? From the same class? Is it Base64-encoded?

Comment: @Thilo AESEncrypter encrypter = new AESEncrypter("staticpassword"); and then encrypter.decrypt("encodedstring");

Comment: Where did you get `"encodedstring"` from? Does it look like something `encrypt` might produce? Is it Base64-encoded?

Comment: @Thilo, encodedstring it is a previous string that i crypted with String encrypt(String encrypt), yep, it is encoded. Okay.. something like                                                                String message = "staticpassword";
            String password = "PASSWORD";

            AESEncrypter encrypter = new AESEncrypter(password);
            String encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(message);
            String decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(encrypted); works, but if i doing the same thing, taking the encrypted string from file, i get an error (JSON parse)

Comment: a) maybe the saving/loading from file is not working.  b) is the way of passing the IV around safe? does it still work when you encrypt/decrypt in memory, but with two different instances of AESEncrypter?

Comment: @Thilo a) i think its working, because I tested a different algorithm and it reads and writes crypted information at the same save/load methods b) I also use the same key (passPhrase), why should it not work.. I tried to see the debugger where i reading the line from file, and its seems like there was nothing extra, okay, I'll use a different algorithm, but I'll try to do something with this problem, thx

Comment: Can you verify that the IV used to decrypt is the same used to encrypt in the case of a file? You probably need to store it along with the ciphertext.

Comment: @Thilo I think, you're on to something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>*This answer is a complete shot in the dark, but it is plausible.*</sup>

#### Problem:

Currently, you're retrieving the IV as a byte array from the `Cipher` instance for encryption and passing the same byte array to the `Cipher` instance for decryption. The problem might be that this IV is not actually copied and will reflect the state of the execution of the encryption procedure. A common CBC implementation might use the byte array that is supposed to be the IV as a state for the encryption of every block. This state would change after encryption.

Thus, if the decryption works on a wrong IV and the original plaintext was shorter than 16 bytes, this will likely (~255 in 256) lead to a BadPaddingException. If the plaintext is 16 bytes or longer, then you will not see a BadPaddingException, but the first 16 bytes will look like garbage. I suggest that you look into how [CBC mode works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_.28CBC.29).

#### Possible solution:

You need to *copy* the IV. So this should suffice:

```
dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(Arrays.copyOf(iv, iv.length)));
```

---

#### Proper solution:

Keep in mind that this only works if you encrypt and decrypt during one execution of the program. If you want to decrypt in a different execution, you need to store the IV somehow.

Since the IV does not need to be secret, it can be sent along with the ciphertext. It is customary to prepend it to the ciphertext and slice it off before decryption.

The salt should also be random and you can send it along with the ciphertext in the same way as the IV.

---

#### Security consideration:

The ciphertext is not authenticated. Thus, you cannot detect (malicious) manipulation. It is best to use authenticated modes like GCM/EAX or use an encrypt-then-MAC scheme with a strong MAC like HMAC-SHA256.